# Determine when Canada’s Population will equal 75 million (SFU Mathematics 180)

Tags: calculus

Suppose the population of Canada at the end of 2010 was 35 million, and that the population $P(t)$ of Canada, in millions, $t$ years after the end of 2010 satisfies the differential equation

$dP/dt = 0.02(P+5)$

Determine when Canada’s population will equal 75 million. Hint: Make a substitution.

Picture of the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQiL9.jpg

Edit: This is what I have so far but I don't know if it is correct.

I substituted $Q = P + 5$ into the differential equation.

$dP/dt = 0.02 Q$

$dP = 0.02Q dt$

Took the integral:

$P = 0.02Qt$

$P = 0.02 (P+5) t$

$75 = 0.02 (75+5) t$

$75 = 0.02 (80) t$

$75/0.02(80) = t$

$t = 46.875$ so the population will reach 75 million people when it is 2057 (2010+57).

My second attempt with another method: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mixt.jpg

Third attempt, solved! https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWw17.jpg

Comment: Very similar to: https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/suppose-that-the-population-pt-of-a-country-satisfies-the-differential-equation-dpdt-d-kp200-p-with/

Comment: Suggestion:  substitute $Q=P+5$

Comment: look, it's *Canada*

Comment: @J. W. Tanner where would I substitute that to?

Comment: put $Q$ instead of $P+5$ in the differential equation

Comment: The question ignores the effects of global warming.

Comment: And it ignore that of AI ;) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{dP}{dt} = 0.02(P+5)$

Let $Q=P+5$.  Then $\dfrac{dQ}{dt}=\dfrac{dP}{dt}$, so $\dfrac{dQ}{dt}=0.02Q$.

Can you solve the differential equation now?

What is $Q$ when $P=35?\;  75?$

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: for the answer, I got $\ln(2)/0.02\approx35$ years after $2010$

Comment: $\dfrac{dQ}{dt}=cQ$ is a very basic differential equation

Comment: I solved it, thank you so much!

Comment: Your second attempt answer still does not match mine numerically

Comment: I just added a pic of my third attempt :D

Comment: Looks good; third time is a charm, they say

Answer (score 0):

Given differential equation, $$\cfrac{dP}{dt} = 0.02(P+ 5)$$. On making the substitution $G = P + 5, \Rightarrow \cfrac{dG}{dt} = \cfrac{dP}{dt} $ , now the equation becomes $$ \cfrac{dG}{dt} = 0.02 G, \Rightarrow G = G_0 e^{0.02t} \Rightarrow (P+5) = (P_0 + 5) e^{0.02t}$$ where $P_0 = 35$. Plug in the values of $P$, and you will get value for $t$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: $P$ is supposed to be in millions

Comment: Oh, I edited that, thanks.

Comment: and why did you say $P_0=10$?

Comment: Oh I thought canada's population now is 10 milion.